# NSMetaDataQuery does not complete

Tags: swift3, icloud, nsmetadataquery

I’m trying to explore the files available to my app in iCloud using `NSMetaDataQuery`.  I’m able to start the query, but it never finishes.  Here’s my code.

```
func report1() {
    let filemgr = FileManager.default
    let url = filemgr.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)
    guard url != nil else {
        print("url is nil")
        return
    }
    let metaDataQuery = NSMetadataQuery()
    metaDataQuery.predicate =
        NSPredicate(format: "%K like '*'", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey)
    metaDataQuery.searchScopes = [NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope]
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(didFinish),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name.NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGathering,
                                           object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(didStart),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name.NSMetadataQueryDidStartGathering,
                                           object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(didUpdate),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name.NSMetadataQueryDidUpdate,
                                           object: nil)
    let result = metaDataQuery.start()
    print("metaDataQuery.start() returned \(result)")
}

@objc func didStart(notification: NSNotification) {
    let query: NSMetadataQuery = notification.object as! NSMetadataQuery
    print("didStart found \(query.results.count) items")
}

@objc func didFinish(notification: NSNotification) {
    print("didFinish")
}

@objc func didUpdate(notification: NSNotification) {
    print("didUpdate")
}
```

This prints the following:

```
didStart found 0 items
metaDataQuery.start() returned true
```

`didStart` is getting called, but `didFinish` and `didUpdate` are never called.  I get the same results if I substitute `==` or `==[cd]` for `like` in the predicate.  Changing `NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope` to `NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDataScope` has no effect. What am I missing?

The same issue seems to have been posed several times on this forum, but I'm not finding any satisfactory answers.

Answer (score 3):

I think I found what is the reason.
Your code

```
let metaDataQuery = NSMetadataQuery()
```

This actually makes the metaDataQuery as **local** object, its lifecycle is in the function scope, and will be destroyed when the function ends. Then how can it work?
Please make it as a member field.

Comment: No, that doesn't work either.  I moved the declaration to the object scope and got the same result.  I think it's because the local variable is actually a pointer to the NSMetadataQuery object.  Calling metaDataQuery.start() will cause a copy of the pointer to be cached in the implementing code, so the object will not be garbage collected.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem was I wasn't calling query.start() from the main thread (I found the [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501095/nsmetadataquery-never-calls-back-with-nsmetadataquerydidfinishgatheringnotificat).

For me the fix was as simple as:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.query.start()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
    NSPredicate(format: "%K like '*'", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey)
```

to

```
    NSPredicate(format: "%K like '*.*'", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey)
```

Comment: Either of these will work (depending on what you are looking for) :-)